# Nintendo Wiimote & Nunchuck key mapping to work with Ubuntu 20.10 or 21.04 - the best way?

Tags: 20.10, 21.04

I am attempting to get a Nintendo Wiimote & Nunchuck key mapping to work with Ubuntu 20.10 or 21.04, The first step is to get the key mapping from the wiimote button presses mapped to other keys.

I have a temporary solution of using the AntiMicro GUI on Ubuntu 20.10, so I can now interact with the Wiimote's 11 buttons. This solution is not ideal at all as it's x11 based and so does not work with Ubuntu 21.04(wayland). Neither is it via the command line. At some point a complete driver that allows all the sensors to work as well.

The software language I am using does not recognise non-standard keys easily – that includes the up arrow etc. So key mapping is important to my project.

Does anyone have a good way to get the wiimote working with key mapping on Ubuntu 20.10 or 21.04?

**My research so far:**

4 methods that are command line based.
Three of these methods are identified on the retropie website, here is the link for the retropie article: https://retropie.org.uk/docs/Wiimote-Controller/
The 4th is a solution one guy created to get his specific custom game controller working and written in python. But that was not for wiimote.
Two or more methods of GUI based solutions.
One of these is 'AntiMicro' and another program referenced by this project is 'Steam controller'. Steam Controller may supercede the AntiMicro effort, I haven't checked it out.  I guess there are other GUI solutions.

Method 1 - wminput.

I explored with the article from this website, lifewire.
https://www.lifewire.com/use-nintendo-wii-controller-linux-games-2202065
The results of my testing are very below. I couldn't get it to work at all, possibly low batteries in the wiimote affected some of my testing.  I will retest when i have another bash. I only touched on wmgui.

Method 2 - moltengamepad
I didn't test this method at all, the testing so far by their team is  done on Arch linux. maybe this is the way to go.

Method 3- xwiimote. Looks like an outdated method, that used to work and I did not investigate. The creator works for Red Hat these days, and my interest is to see this working on Ubuntu.

Method 4 -custom game controller but not for any controllers such as wiimote. https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/bxims5/anoterh_approach_at_joystick_mapping/

GUI methods:
I got AntiMicro to work on Ubuntu 2010. It is GUI, not complete drivers for this game controller. Works for button presses for the Wiimote. Does not work on Wayland.

Steam controller. Not investigated yet.

---

The results of my testing for the article in lifewire related to method 1. I followed the instructions in the article on various computers.

**Ubuntu 20.04.2**

On a 10 year old HP(x64), also on regular desktop(x64)

when I get to:
Sudo apt install wminput

error message
E: Unable to locate package wminput

so failed here

**Ubuntu 20.10**

On a raspberry pi400(ARM) when I try to run

sudo wminput -c /etc/cwiid/wminput/gamepad

I get the error:
Segmentation fault

so failed here

**Ubuntu 21.04 (wayland)**

On both a raspberry pi400(ARM) and on an old HP(x64) I got the same outcome

When trying to run:
sudo wminput -c /etc/cwiid/wminput/gamepad

I got the error message:

ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cwiid.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyVarObject_CallFunction

so failed here

**Ubuntu 21.04(on X11)**

Not tested here, will on my next bash at this problem.

**Raspberry PI OS (march 4th 2021)**

On a raspberry pi400. when I tried to run wmgui I got unexpected write errors. So no joy here. Only breifly explored, and it was when the batteries were going flat.

Raspberry PI OS is included, as if it works here then why not Ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried writing your own driver